# Work done by radiation on an electron

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radiation

I'm studying quantum mechanics (already done with relativity) and I'm trying to understand the matter-radiation interactions. It's said everywhere that matter emits or absorbs photons but nowhere it's said in which way.
When an electron for example emits a photon it's because it's energetically charged, what I don't understand at all is the absorption of a photon.
There are 2 ways I can interpret this:

#1) A way to explain this process (which is probably wrong) is that the electromagnetic field generated by a radiation does a work on the electron and when the work is equal to a quantum of energy needed for the electron to change it's potential  the photon is absorbed (like vanishes) and the electron change "orbit" (it's charged and goes further following the wave position function)
But how can it be possible if electrons are in a volume and the electromagnetic field seems to me (maybe the photon generated  electromagnetic field that spreads in some way ) to be in a line (curve following general relativity if speed of reference $\neq 0$)? What I'm trying to say is that the measure of the probability function of a particle spread in a volume to be along a curve is 0 and so it's the work done from the line because the field just  intersects the "trajectory" of the electron.
What I see (possibly wrong) is that the electromagnetic field on the photon  acts in a curve and not on a volume.

#2) When the photon enters the atom (I don't know how it can do that because I know that an electron may be everywhere but most probably "on the orbit") it just gives up energy and is absorbed (vanishes)

(I know about the Compton effect and about emissions, but everywhere it's explained like photons hits the electron, but this seems impossible to me)